# How to create an ordered list based on an object key/value paring?

Tags: javascript, html, object

I am trying to render a high score ordered list using an JavaScript object that looks something like this:

```
{user1: 5, user2: 10}
```

Using the following code I can generate each list item individual:

```
Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = `${key}: ${value}`;
    scoreList.append(li);
});
```

Now I am looking for a way to sort each list item based on the object value. I know we have the sort function that works on arrays and using the following code almost works:

```
const keysSorted = Object.entries(data).sort((a, b) => {
    return data[a] - data[b];
});
```

However it does not keep the object values, it just returns a sorted array with each key. My wanted result looks like this:

```
<ol>
    <li>user2: 10</li>
    <li>user1: 5</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: In your `sort` callback, `a` and `b` are arrays with two elements. Maybe you meant `a[1] - b[1]`?

Comment: @4castle I feel stupid... you where right. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the small flaw in `.sort`, you can just *reduce it back* to it's previous form. Just map the key/value back to an object:

```js
const data = { user1: 5, user2: 10 };
const keysSorted = Object.entries(data)
  .sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])
  .reduce((a, b) => Object.assign(a, { [b[0]]: b[1] }), {});
console.log(keysSorted);
```

Notes:

- `[b[0]]` is a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names), it resolves the variable before assigning to the object.
- The function docs: [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Comment: should this be ok:`Object.entries(data)
    .sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])
    .forEach((user) => {
      const li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerHTML = `${user[0]}: ${user[1]}`;
      scoreList.append(li);
    });`

Comment: Of course, it's perfectly fine, I personally prefer to separate data manipulation (as sorting) from rendering, but it looks good to me